# Normalizing Data using pandas

Tags: pandas

I have below dataframe 'tt' in which second column 'underlier' is a list of dictionary keys where two keys are underliersecurityid and fxspot

[dataframe tt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xszOI.png)

[column = underlier values showing dictionary pair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAc1U.png)

I want to create a dataframe as an output that takes out the keys from underlier and puts against each enterprise id. eg:

EnterpriseID, underliersecurityid, fxspot

I am able to normalize the underlier column itself, however I keep loosing enterprise id. plz suggest if there is some way to handle this

```
tt = bn.iloc[:,[4,-7]]
tt

ttu = pd.DataFrame(bn.iloc[:,-7].values.tolist()).dropna()
ttu
ttu2 = pd.DataFrame(ttu.iloc[:,0].values.tolist()).dropna()
ttu2
```

Comment: really difficult to answer with screen shots.  Share your data,  `bn.head(5).to_clipboard()`.  should be simple to resolve with one of `explode()` `Series` or `json_normalize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synthesising data.  `explode()` the **list** then use `json_normalize()` on output of `to_dict()` to expand **dict** into columns

```
tt = pd.DataFrame([{"enterpriseid":"abcd","underlyer":[{"underlyersecurityid":"SWAP10Y","fmspot":[]}]}])

pd.json_normalize(tt.explode("underlyer").to_dict(orient="records"))
```

### output

```
enterpriseid underlyer.underlyersecurityid underlyer.fmspot
        abcd                       SWAP10Y               []
```